# convrt List to Hash Map with Stream

Tags: java, stream

I have this List: `List<String> g= Arrays.asList("aa","ab","aaa","aaaa");`

How can I print the output **using java streams**:

```
{2=[2]}  //two-letter word = 2
{3=[1]}  //three-letter word = 1
{4=[1]}  //four-letter word = 1
```

I write this:

```
g.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length)).forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(String.format(k,v)));
```

but print on the output:

```
{2=[aa, ab]}
{3=[aaa]}
{4=[aaaa]}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us what you have tried so far and what the output is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> g= Arrays.asList("aa","ab","aaa","aaaa");
        g.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length))
                .forEach((k,v) -> System.out.printf("{%d=[%d]}%n",k ,v.size()));
```

Output:

```
{2=[2]}
{3=[1]}
{4=[1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```java
List<String> g = Arrays.asList("aa", "ab", "aaa", "aaaa");

g.stream()
    .map(value -> String.format("{%s=[%s]}", g.indexOf(value), value))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
{0=[aa]}
{1=[ab]}
{2=[aaa]}
{3=[aaaa]}
```

Comment: thanks you for this answer,i very nob in stream!First it has to print the number of letters and face the number of words from the number of those letters

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
 g.stream().forEach(elt ->{
            System.out.println("{"+ g.indexOf(elt)+"=["+elt+"]}");
        });
```